# Accelerating the index in huge sparse matrix during loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, sparse-matrix

I need to construct a huge sparse matrix in iterations. The code is as follow:

```
function Huge_Matrix = Create_Huge_Matrix(len, Weight, Index)

    k = size(Weight,1);

    Huge_Matrix = spalloc(len, len,floor(len*k));


    parfor i = 1:len
        temp = sparse(1,len);
        ind = Index(:,i);
        temp(ind) = Weight(:,i);
        Huge_Matrix(i,:) = temp;
    end


    Huge_Matrix = Huge_Matrix + spdiags(-k*ones(len,1),0,len,len);


end
```

As is shown, `len` is size of the height * weight of the input image, for 200*200 image, the `len` is 40000! And I am assigning the `Weight` into this huge matrix according the position stored in `Index`. Even though I use `parfor` to accerlate the loop, the speed is very slow.

I also try to create full matrix at first, it seems that the code can becomes faster, but memory is limited. Is there any other way to speed up the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn’t know sparse matrices work with `parfor`. In any case, copying that data back and forth between processes is going to be more costly than the indexing operation. `parfor` is useful for expensive computations, not for trivial copying.

Comment: The question here is why do you need a 40kx40k matrix? There likely is a better approach to do whatever you’re trying to do.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Because I need to construst a Laplacian matrix.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ar... I thought that parfor could reduce the time of foor loop...

Comment: But what do you need the Laplacian matrix for? I don’t know any graph algorithms applied to images that need the Laplacian matrix to be constructed explicitly.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I need to construct a Laplacian matrix to solve for an ADMM (alternating directions methods of multipliers) problem. It involves the optimization of Laplacian of the original image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@CrisLuengo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58679532/accerlating-the-index-in-huge-sparse-matrix-during-loop-in-matlab#comment103662862_58679532) says in the comments, there is probably a better way to do what you're trying to do than to create a 40kx40k matrix, but if you *have* to create a large sparse matrix, it's better to let MATLAB do it for you.

The [sparse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function has a signature that takes lists of rows, columns and the corresponding values for the nonzero elements of the matrix:

> `S = sparse(i,j,v)` generates a sparse matrix `S` from the triplets `i`, `j`, and `v` such that `S(i(k),j(k)) = v(k)`. The `max(i)-by-max(j)` output matrix has space allotted for `length(v)` nonzero elements. `sparse` adds together elements in `v` that have duplicate subscripts in `i` and `j`.
>
> If the inputs `i`, `j`, and `v` are vectors or matrices, they must have the same number of elements. Alternatively, the argument `v` and/or one of the arguments `i` or `j` can be scalars.

So, we can simply pass `Index` as the row indices and `Weight` as the values, so all we need is an array of column indices the same size as `Index`:

```
col_idx = repmat(1:len, k, 1);
Huge_Matrix = sparse(Index, col_idx, Weight, len, len);
```

(The last two parameters specify the size of the sparse matrix.)

The next step is to create another large sparse matrix and add it to the first. That seems kind of wasteful, so why not just add those entries to the existing arrays before creating the matrix?

Here's the final function:

```
function Huge_Matrix = Create_Huge_Matrix(len, Weight, Index)

   k = size(Weight,1);
    
   % add diagonal indices/weights to arrays
   % this avoids creating second huge sparse array 
   Index(end+1, :) = [1:len];
   Weight(end+1, :) = -k*ones(1,len);
   
   % create array of column numbers corresponding to each Index
   % make k+1 rows because we've added the diagonal
   col_idx = repmat(1:len, k+1, 1);

   % let sparse do the work
   Huge_Matrix = sparse(Index, col_idx, Weight, len, len);

end
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! Very useful! I didnt know this usage before. Let me try after back to office.